# how to set autoplay=true in google audio player?

Tags: .net, audio

i am using google audio player in asp.net website and i want to set autoplay=true by default,when a page loads.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to many questions use below code :)

```
........3523697345-audio-player.swf" flashvars="audioUrl=somewhare/itsdone.mp3&autoPlay=true"width="380" height="27" quality="best"></embe......
```

REMEMBER it's `"autoPlay=true"` not `"autoplay=true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
&autoPlay=false
```

to the url.